# I need to update only the new records and the rest of tare unchanged

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have a stored procedure that updates a column in a table when another table is changed, but when that happens it changes the volumes all referring to the table id and I didn't want that to happen, I just wanted the new records to be changed
Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SubMensal_update]

AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE      EmpAttendance
SET   SubDiario = 


(select SubDiario
FROM EmpSalary 
 WHERE EmpAttendance.time_registered> GETDATE() -1)

END
```

Comment: And what identifies your new records?

Comment: It's seems that you should join tables before update

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: EmpAttendance.time_registered because is time stamp colunn i think.....sorry but i m new in this thanks

Comment: Your update has no `where` clause. What else do you expect it to do?

Comment: @Arvo i have a timestamp colunn in EmpAttendance and the colunn SubDiario get  the data from EmpSalary.SubDiario i dont know if works but i thanks fot you help

Comment: @LevGelman the  colunn SubDiario get the data from EmpSalary.SubDiario and the table EmpAttendance could have many registres for thr same id in diferent months and te SubDiario can change

Comment: @Stu  WHERE EmpAttendance.time_registered> GETDATE() -1) but dont work my friend

Comment: @MiguelSantos re-read your code - that is the `where` clause on your `sub-select`. your update reads `update EmpAttendance set subDiario=X`

Comment: @Stu can you help me please?or better teacht me many thanks

Comment: You haven't given us any info to work with. I don't know your table schema or how you correlate between the two. Your sub-select could return 1 or 1000 rows,

Comment: @Stu its a simple payroll in c# whith localdb the table EmpSalary have Id,JoinDate, Salary, and  food allowance per month but you cam change salary and food alowance,the table EmpAttendance its wuere you vcan see the working days absentdays etc an d have a computed colunn that gives the  food alowance in month based em absent days etc and have a colunn food alowance who gets the data in EmpSalary

Comment: @Stu apologizes for not being able to be more concise, but the only thing I need is that when changing the SubDiary column in the EmpSalary table, only change the new records in the SubDiary column in the EmpAttendance table, ie Id = 1. mes = March, year 2021, SubDiary = 30000, when changing SubDiary in EmpSalary, to 15000 in April, Id = 1. mes = April, year 2021, SubDiario = 15000 and March keeps the 30000 that already had excuse for my ignorance ,thank you very much

Comment: You need to put the work in to add the proper information in your question if you expect others to be able help you, please refer to [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Will have a guess at the following being what you need, without seeing the actual tables and data involved it can only be a guess.

```
update a set 
    a.SubDiario=s.SubDiario
from EmpAttendance a 
join EmpSalary s on s.Id=a.Id --<<< This is a guess, you need to join on the correct foreign key
where a.time_registered > getdate() -1
```

Comment: Thanks lot brother, you are the man, now i will try to make a trigger with it